# Cronjob timeout to multiple jobs

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron, telegram-bot

I'm working on a Telegram bot.
I use `Telegraf` and `cron` for notifications.
Telegram may send only 30 messages per second. Therefore I'm looking for a solution to schedule jobs running at the same time when they exceed the limits.

Here is the sample script of the cronjob I'm using:

```js
async function setCronJob(chat_id, time, tz) {
  const cronTime = moment.isMoment(time) ? time.toDate() : `${time.m} ${time.h} * * *`;
  const job = new CronJob({
    cronTime,
    async onTick() {
        const user = await db.User.findOne({chat_id: chat_id})
        await bot.telegram.sendMessage(user.chat_id, 'Hello World')
    },
    start: true,
    timeZone: tz
  });
  job.start()
}
```

Please suggest which solutions I could use in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing cronjob for this, I would suggest you use queues for this functionality. What queues do is they "queue" up functionalities that you wanna implement.

In particular, you could read up on `bull` library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/bull

It provides queueing functionality as well as time-defined jobs to be implemented at a certain time.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll take a look at it.